# getting error as Internal Server error

Tags: php, apache, web-services

When I try to run my site it gives error as Internal Server error, when I refresh the page I get my result properly.The error page looks like this:

**Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@test.mywebsite.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.**

I also checked error_log file on my server, it gives error as:
[Sat Jun 12 01:21:55 2010] [error] [client 117.195.6.76] File does not exist: /home/rohit25/public_html/test/500.shtml, referer: http://www.test.mysite.com/home.php

sometimes error can be;
[Sat May 29 19:35:12 2010] [error] [client 97.85.189.208] File does not exist: /home2/carlton/public_html/test/favicon.ico

Are there any changes required in configuration file, I also tried to involve this error code in custom error page, it shows error page, which could not resolve this issue.

Your urgent help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using htacces/url rewriting?

Comment: Yes, I am using .htaccess file in which various errors are like 400, 401, 404, 301, 403, 408, 405, are customized.

Answer (score 1):

The two errors you posted from your log are 404 errors. You need to configure your server to report HTTP 500 errors, which are those Internal Server Errors causing the message above.

Comment: I have included this error in .htaccess file. can you elaborate on these settings Ben please?